# What is the difference between injection through the constructor and injection through field annotations with Guice?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have the below code to do dependency injection using Guice. The first one is using constructor injection while the other one is adding `@Inject` directly above the field. Is there any difference between these two ways? It seems that constructor injection is recommended on the Guice official website.

```
class BillingService {
    private final CreditCardProcessor processor;
    private final TransactionLog transactionLog;

    @Inject
    BillingService(CreditCardProcessor processor, TransactionLog transactionLog) {
        this.processor = processor;
        this.transactionLog = transactionLog;
    }
    ...
}
```

And:

```
class BillingService {
    @Inject
    private final CreditCardProcessor processor;
    @Inject
    private final TransactionLog transactionLog;
    BillingService() {

    }
    ...       
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences I would point:

- without constructor injection you won't be able to use the `final` modifier, i.e. your code above won't compile. Commenting the advantages of final members is off-topic here.
- with constructor injection all dependencies are kind of mandatory. You won't be able to instantiate the class without knowing about each declared dependency.
- writing test cases with constructor injection might be easier (see the answer of The111).
- there is another type of DI - setter injection - which can be more naturally mixed with constructor injection (e.g. for separating mandatory and optional dependencies).

Answer (score 4):

Here's one difference. In the latter case, injection is the only way you can completely construct an instance of `BillingService`. If for whatever reason you need to build one without injection, you can't (using the methods shown, at least).

In the former case, you can still build one the old fashioned way, if you have some reason to want to do that:

```
new BillingService(someProcessor, someLog);
```

I've worked on one team that did it one way, and another that did it the other way. In most cases I used injection all the time, even for test. But every once in a while in a unit test I find it convenient to construct something the non-Guicy way, and in those cases the constructor injection does buy you that flexibility.